# HTML Anchor settings

Tags: html, asp.net, anchor

Is there a way to force an anchor to be at the middle or bottom of the screen upon press?

The reason i ask is because i have an ASP.net document which will load from a database and give a long form. I have an anchor situated at the top and it works great, except that it takes the browser to the start of the ASP form instead of the top of the page. which is to be expected. but is there any way around that?

example of what happens currently:

```
OnButtonClick:     
                      banner (offscreen)
    --------------    --------------
    |banner      |    |anchor      |
    |anchor      |    |asp doc     |
    |asp doc     |    | .          |
    | .          |    | ..         |
    | ..         |    | ...        |
    | ...        |    |button      |
    |button      |    |            |
    |____________|    |____________|
```

i Should probably add:

I can't add an anchor to the html document itself because this ASP form will not be in a constant location. it could be on as many as 10  different websites. which different layouts.

**Thanks Banana for a working Solution:**

```
<script>
function anchor() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
}
</script>

<a onclick="anchor()">
    <asp:Image ID="TopOfPageButton" ImageUrl="~/Images/topofpage.gif" runat="server" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could navigate to any element if you add #[elemendID] to the query string

for example, u have an element with id="banana"

you could focus on it by loading your page this way:

```
http://blablablablabla.com/blabla.aspx#banana
```

EDIT:

or like was suggested below, you could use jquery.
you could attach a javascript function to the button's onClientClick event,
and in that function execute

```
$(window).scrollTop(0);
```

Comment: i know. I just added a little quip about that in my question. Basically, the asp document wont have a constant home. it may move around, so i can't necessarily link it to something outside of the asp tags.

Comment: you can use an empty master page with anchor on top, and the contentTemplate right under it.

Comment: The JQuery worked. I actually didn't know prior to this that some HTML tags had sub-routines to call javascript functions.

Comment: glad i could help. as you know, every technology even ASP eventually breaks everything into regular html tags. some have embedded functions like onClick and onClientClick while others dont, however since everything is being broken into html tags anyway, you can simply add html attributes to asp controls as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to link it to a common element that appears in every html document like

```
<div ID="nav">
```

this way all the pages will go up to the top.

Comment: This is not a good idea. First off HTML5 doesn't need a nav div it has a pre-built nav tag. Secondly, you are under the impression every site is going to be the same. What if the the layout was different and they named a footer div nav?